# Accesing the value returned from web service called through soap in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap

I was working with SOAP to access web service. my question is how to retrieve the value returned from web service

This is my SOAP response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <fnPartyQuestionsPathResponse xmlns="http://QIA/">
      <fnPartyQuestionsPathResult>string</fnPartyQuestionsPathResult>
    </fnPartyQuestionsPathResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

THanks in advance..

Comment: parse the xml format obtained and gather the wanted data from xml and use accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) is always worth a look when working with SOAP. It will auto-generate a whole series of classes and objects from your WSDL file (assuming you have access to it) and that makes accessing the data really easy. I've used it on some live projects and find it does what it says on the tin.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply ,i  already have a web service ,its taking 2 string parameters and returning a string value. How can i get that string value using WSDL. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/) library to generate accessor code for your SOAP service, and work with that. I find that it's pretty simple and robust for usage.